# SSRS Cumulative Chart or S graph

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How to create a Column chart with a  cumulative line graph running over the columns. I have a dataset that returns the columns months,Qty1 and Qty2 . Now I need a column chart that compares these two quantities for every month in the column and a cumulative line for each Qty running over the column charts.

Thanks !

Comment: you have access to the datasets the chart is based on. I bet that should set up your charting grouping filters to ignore null or whatever should be ignored. You can control if s value gets through on the group level filter.

Answer (score 0):

To get a line chart on top of your bar chart:

*(Assuming you're using Visual Studio to design your report, these steps may be different in other environments):*

1. Create your bar chart with the monthly bars that you want.
2. Click on the chart, then in the ChartData window that pops up, click the green "+" in the Values section, and add the field that contains the value you want to use in your line chart.
3. Once the value is added, right click it in the ChartData window, and choose "Change Chart Type" - change to a line chart.
4. Tweak your category, series, and axis settings until it renders in a manner you like.

NOTE:  If your cumulative field isn't already a running aggregate, you're going to need to either add such a field to your dataset, or use an expression to work out the aggregation; the line chart won't do that for you.